# Where does the preview screen after taking a picture in cordova come from?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a cordova application for multiple platforms and have a question about the behavior of the camera plugin. I'm using the following one:

`org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.6 "Camera"`

When I call `navigator.camera.getPicture` the camera opens and I can take my picture as expected. After the picture is taken a screen with a preview of the taken photo appears where I can choose "re-take" or "use photo".

The question now is, where does this screen come from? I can't find it in the plugins code. the problem is that this screen really differs on different platforms, means the buttons are at the bottom of the screen on an iOS device, at the top on a samsung android tablet and overlapping the photo on a htc smartphone. Is this screen depending on the respective devices camera-settings? Can it be customized, if yes how?

A further question would be, whether this appearing preview screen can be disabled at all?

Any help or hints are appreciated!